# How to peek into already existing service bus queue?

Tags: windows, azure, servicebus

I understand that I can call the Peek() method on a queue that I create using a connection string. Is there a way for me to get back a QueueClient entity using some sort of Get if I have the queue name? After doing this I want to call the Peek() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of queues via the `NamespaceManager`:

```
NamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("connection_string_here");
Console.WriteLine("List of queues:");
IEnumerable <QueueDescription> queueList = nameSpaceManager.GetQueues();
foreach (QueueDescription qd in queueList)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Queue name {0}", qd.Path, qd.MessageCount);
}
```

Once you know the queue name, create a `QueueClient` and do your peek.